# How to create a query in AzureDevops using API request without having an query-ID

Tags: azure, devops, azure-rest-api

I am trying to create a query in AzureDevops using REST API.

I found this in the docs:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=7.0

{
  "name": "All Bugs",
  "wiql": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```

I'm wondering what to use as the `{query}` parameter? I think its the query ID but how can I create a query using the API without knowing the ID beforehand?

I have tried using no ID at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, you need to use **path** under which the query is to be created as `{query}` parameter for creating query.

I have few **work items** in my Azure DevOps project created for testing purpose like this:

[image]

Initially, I created one **folder** inside **`My Queries`** by executing below REST API call:

```http
POST https://dev.azure.com/org_name/proj_name/_apis/wit/queries/My Queries?api-version=7.0

{
  "name": "Demo folder",
  "isFolder": true
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I used **path** from above response for  `{query}` parameter to create a new query like this:

```http
POST https://dev.azure.com/org_name/proj_name/_apis/wit/queries/My Queries?api-version=7.0

{
  "name": "All Tasks",
  "wiql": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Azure DevOps portal where query created successfully like below:

[image]

If you want to **move specific query** to any other folder, then **query ID** is required for `{query}` parameter.

**Reference:**
[Queries - Create - REST API (Azure DevOps Work Item Tracking) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#uri-parameters)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it worked like a charm :)